# Fiji(ImageJ) takes too long to load (on linux), together with a lengthy error message

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, imagej

I'm using Fiji on linux (inside a virtual machine) from the command line.
Specifically I have a python script that calls many fiji macros. 
Each time fiji loads it takes about a minute, making it the bottleneck of the process and slowing me considerably.

I wonder if this is normal. Could fiji perhaps be made to load more quickly?
Fiji also outputs a lengthy error message when it is called. I wonder if it is related to the lengthy time it takes to load.

The command I use to call it (for example)

```
//shared_directory/projects/Fiji.app/ImageJ-linux64 --headless 
-macro //shared_directory/projects/retracted/fiji_scripts/patch_cropper.txt
```

The error message is as follows

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
        at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
        at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
        at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
        at ij.plugin.frame.PlugInFrame.<init>(PlugInFrame.java:13)
        at ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager.<init>(RoiManager.java:94)
        at ij.macro.Interpreter.getBatchModeRoiManager(Interpreter.java:1875)
        at ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager.getInstance(RoiManager.java:1795)
        at ij.ImagePlus.deleteRoi(ImagePlus.java:1735)
        at ij.ImagePlus.close(ImagePlus.java:391)
        at ij.plugin.Commands.closeImage(Commands.java:136)
        at ij.plugin.Commands.close(Commands.java:83)
        at ij.plugin.Commands.run(Commands.java:29)
        at ij.IJ.runPlugIn(IJ.java:187)
        at ij.Executer.runCommand(Executer.java:137)
        at ij.Executer.run(Executer.java:66)
        at ij.IJ.run(IJ.java:297)
        at ij.IJ.run(IJ.java:272)
        at ij.macro.Functions.doRun(Functions.java:603)
        at ij.macro.Functions.doFunction(Functions.java:96)
        at ij.macro.Interpreter.doStatement(Interpreter.java:230)
        at ij.macro.Interpreter.doStatements(Interpreter.java:218)
        at ij.macro.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:115)
        at ij.macro.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:85)
        at ij.macro.Interpreter.run(Interpreter.java:96)
        at ij.plugin.Macro_Runner.runMacro(Macro_Runner.java:155)
        at ij.plugin.Macro_Runner.runMacroFile(Macro_Runner.java:139)
        at ij.IJ.runMacroFile(IJ.java:148)
        at net.imagej.legacy.IJ1Helper$4.call(IJ1Helper.java:1056)
        at net.imagej.legacy.IJ1Helper$4.call(IJ1Helper.java:1052)
        at net.imagej.legacy.IJ1Helper.runMacroFriendly(IJ1Helper.java:986)
        at net.imagej.legacy.IJ1Helper.runMacroFile(IJ1Helper.java:1052)
        at net.imagej.legacy.LegacyCommandline$Macro.handle(LegacyCommandline.java:188)
        at org.scijava.console.DefaultConsoleService.processArgs(DefaultConsoleService.java:102)
        at net.imagej.legacy.LegacyConsoleService.processArgs(LegacyConsoleService.java:81)
        at org.scijava.AbstractGateway.launch(AbstractGateway.java:95)
        at net.imagej.Main.launch(Main.java:62)
        at net.imagej.Main.main(Main.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at net.imagej.launcher.ClassLauncher.launch(ClassLauncher.java:279)
        at net.imagej.launcher.ClassLauncher.run(ClassLauncher.java:186)
        at net.imagej.launcher.ClassLauncher.main(ClassLauncher.java:77)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot handle app name in ij.gui.YesNoCancelDialog's public <init>(java.awt.Frame parent, java.lang.String title, java.lang.String msg)
        at net.imagej.patcher.CodeHacker.replaceAppNameInCall(CodeHacker.java:446)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyExtensions.insertAppNameHooks(LegacyExtensions.java:419)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyExtensions.injectHooks(LegacyExtensions.java:291)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyInjector.inject(LegacyInjector.java:308)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyInjector.injectHooks(LegacyInjector.java:109)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyEnvironment.initialize(LegacyEnvironment.java:101)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyEnvironment.applyPatches(LegacyEnvironment.java:495)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyInjector.preinit(LegacyInjector.java:397)
        at net.imagej.patcher.LegacyInjector.preinit(LegacyInjector.java:376)
        at net.imagej.legacy.LegacyService.<clinit>(LegacyService.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.createServiceRecursively(ServiceHelper.java:302)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.createExactService(ServiceHelper.java:269)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.loadService(ServiceHelper.java:231)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.createServiceRecursively(ServiceHelper.java:340)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.createExactService(ServiceHelper.java:269)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.loadService(ServiceHelper.java:231)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.loadService(ServiceHelper.java:194)
        at org.scijava.service.ServiceHelper.loadServices(ServiceHelper.java:166)
        at org.scijava.Context.<init>(Context.java:278)
        at org.scijava.Context.<init>(Context.java:234)
        at org.scijava.Context.<init>(Context.java:174)
        at org.scijava.Context.<init>(Context.java:160)
        at net.imagej.ImageJ.<init>(ImageJ.java:77)
        at net.imagej.Main.launch(Main.java:61)
        at net.imagej.Main.main(Main.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at net.imagej.launcher.ClassLauncher.launch(ClassLauncher.java:279)
        at net.imagej.launcher.ClassLauncher.run(ClassLauncher.java:186)
        at net.imagej.launcher.ClassLauncher.main(ClassLauncher.java:77)
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: No code replaced!
        at net.imagej.patcher.CodeHacker$EagerExprEditor.instrument(CodeHacker.java:1280)
        at net.imagej.patcher.CodeHacker.replaceAppNameInCall(CodeHacker.java:443)
        ... 36 more
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder if this is normal. Could fiji perhaps be made to load more quickly?

I don't think this is intended behavior. As this issue is very specific to ImageJ/Fiji, you should better raise this point on the [ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/).

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot handle app name in ij.gui.YesNoCancelDialog's public <init>(java.awt.Frame parent, java.lang.String title, java.lang.String msg)`

This is likely due to `ij1-patcher` not handling `ij.gui.YesNoCancelDialog` to make it independent on the Java AWT framework (which interferes with the goal of running things headless).

You are welcome to submit a patch to the [`ij1-patcher` project](https://github.com/imagej/ij1-patcher) to make it deal with `YesNoCancelDialog` in a similar way as it currently does with `GenericDialog`, see [these lines](https://github.com/imagej/ij1-patcher/blob/8dcdaf326cae05674d522d89d553808cb309c600/src/main/java/net/imagej/patcher/LegacyHeadless.java#L85-L87).

<s>As a workaround, simply use a macro that doesn't use `YesNoCancelDialog`, i.e. does not run the [`getBoolean()` macro function](http://imagej.net/developer/macro/functions.html#getBoolean).</s>

EDIT: as also noted in the [ImageJ forum topic](http://forum.imagej.net/t/fiji-imagej-takes-too-long-to-load-on-linux-together-with-a-lengthy-error-message/4628/4?u=imagejan), a patch was submitted [here](https://github.com/imagej/ij1-patcher/pull/41).

Until this gets merged and released, you can work around the issue by downgrading ij.jar using *Help > Update ImageJ...*

Comment: Thanks.
I fear I did not understand your workaround.

I wrote the macro I run, and (to the best of my knowledge) I did not use a `YesNoCancelDialog` in it.
Indeed, I also get this error without calling any macro:
`//shared_directory/projects/Fiji.app/ImageJ-linux64 --headless -macro`

Comment: As you posted [the same question on the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/fiji-imagej-takes-too-long-to-load-on-linux-together-with-a-lengthy-error-message/4628?u=imagejan) now, let's continue the discussion over there.